# Simpler way to check if a parameter is an Array of a specific type?

Tags: vb.net, casting

Currently I have the method below in a class. When it is called, the class only stores the data if it is an array of length 3 with specific constraints on the first two elements.

However, the following code seems clunky and inefficient to me, especially if I'm dealing with larger arrays. However, without using `Try` blocks I haven't been able to find a better way to do this, and would like to ask here if it is possible.

```
Overrides Sub output(ByVal data As Object)

    Dim array() As Object = TryCast(data, Object())

    If Not array Is Nothing AndAlso array.Length = 3 Then

        For Each element In array
            If Not TypeOf (element) Is Integer Then Return
        Next

        If Not (array(0) = -1 OrElse array(1) = -1) Then

            memory.Add(array)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use stronger typing for the parameter and let the compiler verify this?

Comment: The method is inherited from the base class, so I can't in this case.

Comment: Then there's a problem with the inheritance design. Needing to use `Object` as the type anywhere in .Net is a very strong code smell.

Comment: The class I'm making is an AI. The AI can be sent data (received in `output`) and calculates an input on a separate thread when asked to do so. All of the code to handle the threads is in the base class, and inherited classes only need to have the input/output processing methods overrided. What's wrong with `MustOverride Sub output(ByVal data As Object)` taking generic Objects in the Base?

Answer (score 1):

First off - I would suggest that instead of using `Return`, use `Exit Sub` as that is more obvious and readable.

Based on your code, I'm assuming that the parameter that is passed to the sub could be something other than an array and if it is an array, it could be an array of mixed objects rather than all the elements being integers or singles. If all the elements in the array are always going to be the same type, then rather than check all elements of the array, you can just check that the first element is an integer type.. (this isn't the same as checking if the value itself is an integer of course. you can still have a `Single` type with a value of 1)

For example .. replace the above loop with simply

```
If Not TypeOf (array(0)) Is Integer Then Exit Sub
```

If the array IS of mixed objects, you could try to speed things up by running that check using a `Parallel.ForEach` loop instead .. like this

```
Parallel.ForEach(array,
            Sub(element)
                If Not TypeOf (element) Is Integer Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End Sub)
```

But - the processing overheads of multi-threading the tiny amount of code in the loop will likely cause a performance decrease. If the code in your actual loop is longer, you may get a benefit.

Yet another way is to use the `Array.TrueForAll` function. Replace your loop with

```
If Not System.Array.TrueForAll(array, AddressOf IsIntegerType) Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

and add a function to return true if the object is an integer ..

```
Private Function IsIntegerType(value As Object) As Boolean
    If TypeOf (value) Is Integer Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

You would have to benchmark these to figure out which is quickest in your own code of course. And check memory usage if that could potentially be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see how the `TrueForAll` works out. (btw `IsIntegerType` can just be `Return TypeOf (value) Is Integer`)

Comment: Ha! Yes of course. I did write that at around 0200 :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this for output Sub.  Don't know if it is an improvement.

```
    If data Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim t As Type = data.GetType
    Dim a() As Object
    If t.IsArray Then
        a = DirectCast(data, Object())
        If Not (a IsNot Nothing AndAlso a.Length = 3 AndAlso TypeOf a(0) Is Integer) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'other code
        If Not (CInt(a(0)) = -1 OrElse CInt(a(1)) = -1) Then
            memory.Add(foo)
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: If `a(1)` is something which can't be converted to an integer then you get an exception?

Comment: @Shuri2060 - you didn't say that you were passing mixed data types in the array.  I'd change it to use double or decimal if that is the case.